# way to disassemble windows exe files in linux

Tags: disassembly

Is there any way to disassemble windows exe files in linux?

Would this involve Wine? If so, is there any windows debug/disassembly program available for linux?

And can this be done with gdb?

Thnx.

Answer (score 3):

`objdump -d` works for me (I have version 2.24):

```
$ objdump -d ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Internet\ Explorer/iexplore.exe |head

/home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe:     file format pei-i386
```

Note that I tried other binaries, including ntoskrnl.exe and Steam.exe and they also work with `objdump`

```
Disassembly of section .text:

10001000 <.text>:
10001000:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
10001005:   c2 04 00                ret    $0x4
```

For me, gdb didn't work, even when running with `wine`:

```
/home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe: not an ELF binary... don't know how to load it
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [IDA Debugger](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/linux.shtml) Used it in the past with success.